# simple_form bootstrap 4 radio buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to set simple_form up with bootstrap 4 alpha, I am having trouble with the custom radio buttons. The html output I am trying to get to seems quite straight forward but I cant seem to get the configuration right.

target output:

```
<label class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Label</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Toggle this custom radio</span>
  </label>
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Or toggle this other custom radio</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Attempted config:

```
  config.wrappers :horizontal_radio, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group row', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label, class: 'col-xs-2 col-form-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-xs-10' do |ba|
      ba.wrapper tag: 'label', class: 'custom-control custom-radio' do |bb|
        bb.use :input, class: 'custom-control-input'
        bb.wrapper tag: 'span', class: 'custom-control-indicator' do
        end
        bb.use :label_text, class: 'custom-control-description'
      end
    end
  end
```

current output:

```
<label class="col-xs-2 col-form-label radio_buttons optional">Label</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="hidden" name="store[payment_type]" value="">
    <span class="radio inline">
      <input class="custom-control-input radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" name="store[payment_type]" id="store_payment_type_true">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="store_payment_type_true">Yes</label>
    </span>
    <span class="radio inline">
      <input class="custom-control-input radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" name="store[payment_type]" id="store_payment_type_false">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="store_payment_type_false">No</label>
    </span>
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    Payment type
  </label>
</div>
```

This is not too far off but it is not right and does not currently work. I cant seem to land on the right configuration to get the output correct. I have tried to use `wrap_with` but I need to add extra elements into the wrapper, and the wrapper class only seems to be the form_field wrapper not an item_wrapper.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be really useful.